# It is simplified version of my code. I have a problem with output. How can I fix it?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic

```
int* row;
row = (int*)(malloc)(5 * sizeof(int));
int **s1;
s1=(int**)(malloc)(2*sizeof(row)); 

row[0] = 1;
row[1] = 2;
row[2] = 1;
row[3] = 2;
row[4] = 1;
s1[0] = row;

row[0] = 3;
row[1] = 3;
row[2] = 3;
row[3] = 4;
row[4] = 3;
s1[1] = row;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d", s1[0][i]);
printf("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d", s1[1][i]);
```

my output:

33343

33343

but I want to see

12121

33343

as output. Also, I do not want to use static allocation.

Comment: `s1[0] = row` is a reference to `row`. You then manipulate row's contents and assign a second reference to `s1[1]`. Both `s1[0]` and `s1[1]` point to the same thing (`row`).

Comment: As an aside: ***don't cast malloc() in C !!!*** :-)

Comment: Stated another way (what's already been pointed out)... `s1[0]` and `s1[1]` point to the same array of numbers in memory, those at address `row`. So `s1[0]` and `s1[1]` always point to the same list of numbers. If you want your code to work as expected, you need, for example, separate `row1` and `row2`. You can dynamically allocate both of them.

Answer (score 3):

The both pointers (elements) of the dynamically allocated array of pointers point to the same object row after assignments

```
s1[0] = row;
//...
s1[1] = row;
```

So what is stored in the current moment in the array pointed to by the pointer row is pointed to these two pointers s1[0] and s1[1].

You need set the pointer s1[1] to some other array.